# Setting pixels values in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

How fast change pixels values? In C# what i need to do is only use `GetPixel()` to get pixel value and `SetPixel()` to change it (its pretty easy to use but slow, MarshallCopy and Lock/UnlockBits is much faster).

In this code, i marking black pixels as 1 and white pixels as 0

```
import tkFileDialog
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
bmp = cv2.imread(path) #reading image
height, width, channels = bmp.shape

if channels == 3:
    bmp = cv2.cvtColor(bmp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #if image have 3 channels, convert to BW
    bmp = bmp.astype('uint8')

bmp = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(bmp,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2) #Otsu thresholding

imageData = np.asarray(bmp) #get pixels values

pixelArray = [[0 for y in range(height)] for x in range(width)] #set size of array for pixels

for y in range(len(imageData)):
    for x in range(len(imageData[0])):
        if imageData[y][x] == 0:
            pixelArray[y][x] = 1 #if black pixels = 1
        else:
            pixelArray[y][x] = 0 #if white pixels = 0
```

In c#, it can looks like this:

```
for (y = 0; y < bmp.Height-1; y++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < bmp.Width-1; x++)
                {
                    if (pixelArray[y, x] == 1)
                        newImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black); //printing new bitmap
                    else
                        newImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                }
            }
            image2.Source = Bitmap2BitmapImage(newImage);
```

In the next step i will marking countour pixels as "2", but now i want to ask you, how to set new image in python from my specific value and then, display it? For experimental purpose, i want to invert image (from B&W to W&B) only by byte valuse. Can you help me how to do it?

**EDIT1**

I think i found a solution, but i have GREYSCALE image with one channel (i think thats how it works when i using `cv2.cvtColor` to convert 3 channels image to greyscale image). The function like this:

```
im[np.where((im == [0,0,0]).all(axis = 2))] = [0,33,166]
```

Could work pretty well, but how to make that function work with greyscale image? I want to set some black pixels (0) into White (255)

Comment: If black is 0 and white is 1, you can invert with `image=1-image`. If black is 0 and white is 255, you can invert with image=255-image.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But i dont want to simply invert image but sett pixels values according to my `pixelArray[][]`, when "1" - black, when "0" - white. I asking about it because in next step i wil get "2" as countour so it will start to be more complicated

Comment: You might like to consider a LUT... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50598388/2836621

Comment: I just trying to implement KMM skelezation alghoritm, block diagram here

https://imgur.com/a/zNq7D75

Comment: I dont really need LUT because i have only two pixels value, White (255) and Black (0). 

"1s" and "2s" are Black, "0s" are White

In the last step i will have (in `pixelArray`) values like 0, 1 or 2. According to this matrix, i want to set every pixel (`pixel[y][x] == pixelArray[y][x]`) compared to values in `pixelArray` (im deleting countur marked as "2", so "2" pixels == (255)

Comment: I found a solution, but when i add an line like that: `bmp[np.where((bmp == [0,0,0]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]` (i could write that line in some `if`statements) i get an error : `AttributeError("'bool' object has no attribute 'all'",)`

Comment: i edited main post with solution that i think will help me

Comment: @metadon789 is your question solved or are you facing any problem still?

Comment: Yes ofc, in Python and OpenCV we can acces to pixel easier that i thought, image[y,x] and you acces to specific pixel. Your response was really helpful too, thanks! I see NumPy have something liek LINQ in c#, great news for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single channel image (gray scale image) use the following:

First create a copy of the gray image:

```
gray_2 = gray.copy()
```

Now assign black pixels to be white:

```
gray_2[np.where(gray == 0)] = 255
```