# Map 3 channel image to 1 channel using custom colormap

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to figure out how to use the OpenCV function LUT to map some of the 3-channel pixels of my image to a value defined as a mapping function. I can hard code this with a for loop and some switch-case, but I would like to see how to do it wit OpenCV.
Here below is the mapping criterium, which means that the mapping is [0,0,0] -> 0, [255,0,0] -> 1, [255,255,0] -> 2, etc.
I didn't find OpenCV documentation very intuitive to solve this problem. Can someone help me with this using Python?

labelmap = [0   0   0   ; 255   0   0   ; 255   255 0   ; 128   0   255 ; 255   128 0   ; 0 0   255 ; 128   255 255; 0  255 0]

This is my current solution to this without LUT:

```
import numpy as np

label = np.zeros((5,5,3))
label[0,0,:] = [255,0,0]
label[1,0,:] = [255,255,0]
label[2,0,:] = [0,255,0]

print label

out_label = np.zeros((label.shape[0], label.shape[1]))
mapping = {(0,0,0): 0,
(255,0,0): 1, 
(255,255,0): 2, 
(128,0,255): 3,
(255,128,0): 4,
(0,0,255): 5,
(0,255,0): 6
}

for i in range(label.shape[0]):
    for j in range(label.shape[1]):
        out_label[i,j] = mapping[tuple(label[i,j,:])]

print out_label
```

Comment: [`cv2.LUT`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab55b8d062b7f5587720ede032d34156f) is no use here, it applies a non-sparse (must have 256 entries) table to each channel independently. You can probably get better performance by using vectorized numpy functions... maybe something like [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)?

Comment: I did something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50598388/2836621